# Problem with gnome appearance

Tags: gnome, 13.10, gnome-classic, visualization

I am trying to configure my ubuntu (13.10) to get this appearance:
[image: appearance]

I ran into a few problems.

1. 13.10 uses unity. I followed a tutorial to change it to gnome-classic (as that is what I thought I was looking for after a some research).
2. It probably wasn't was I was trying to get. I tried changing and fumbling in all the visual settings I could find to no avail.

   - Everything is white in my version.
   - Workspaces in bottom right are missing.
   - Left bottom icon on taskbar is missing.
   - All icons are different.

I am pretty sure I have gone the wrong way but could not find how it was actually supposed to be done.
(I followed [this tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html).)

I would like this layout as it is the one we use at school.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have figured something out:

1. I needed Gnome Flashback,which started working after a few fixes, it starts looking good now.
2. My cursor is invisible.
3. The initial login screen is different. (not a priority as it seems to work properly)

   - I have a gray one with log-in info in the center.
   - I tried to have one with the login on the left, but it's hard to look for info with no clue as what they're called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found:

```
apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

This installed what I was looking for without any major issues.

You may need to add 'sudo' in front of the command.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```